# Retrieve data between two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I am having trouble with MySQL query, I have a "products" table. In this table I have a "product_expiry" column. I am trying to create a form which will retrieve all products which have "product_expiry" dates between two dates.

For example I want to get products which have "product_expiry" date from "04/2016" to "09/2016".

For this I decided to go with this query.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE MONTH(product_expiry) >= "4" AND MONTH(product_expiry) <= "9" AND YEAR(product_expiry) = "2016"
```

It returned 0 products though I have products between these dates.
I thought the problem is with the format of the date.

Then I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`product_expiry`,'%d,%m,%Y')) >= "4" AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`product_expiry`,'%d,%m,%Y')) <= "9" AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`product_expiry`,'%d,%m,%Y')) = "2016"
```

But it is again returning 0 products.

**NOTE:**
"product_expiry" is varchar not a date column
and Format of the date is day/month/year

Comment: What happens if your are trying with `4, 9, 2016` as integer instead of the `"4", "9", "2016"`?

Comment: It returns 0 products

Comment: 1. Store dates as dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below query. I replaced the `'%d,%m,%Y'` to `'%d/%m/%Y'` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`product_expiry`, '%d/%m/%Y')) >= 4
    AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`product_expiry`, '%d/%m/%Y')) <= 9
    AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`product_expiry`, '%d/%m/%Y')) = 2016
```

Please find the <kbd>[`Working Demo`](http://rextester.com/BTJR76581)</kbd>